# Default spacing rows/columns in xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic, xymatrix

I'm writing up some category theory notes and I prefer (generally) to have 20mm spaces between the entries of my diagrams, so every time I initiate a new matrix I end up typing

`\xymatrixrowsep{20mm}\xymatrixcolsep{20mm}`

before I construct the matrix.  Is there something I can add to my preamble which will set the default spacing to 20mm to avoid this step?

Comment: Did you try setting that in the preamble?

Comment: @egreg No but this is exactly what I'm looking for, where in the preamble would it go? The only reference to xypic I have at all is `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}`.

Comment: @egreg Ha, I just typed it arbitrarily in the preamble and it worked, thanks for the advice.  If only the solution was always this easy :-).  If you wana post it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the setting in the preamble.

There's a simpler method for overriding it, in case of need, as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\xymatrixrowsep{20mm}\xymatrixcolsep{20mm}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{ A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\ C \ar[r] & D }
\]

\[
\xymatrixrowsep{20mm}\xymatrixcolsep{20mm}
\xymatrix{ A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\ C \ar[r] & D }
\]

\[
\xymatrixrowsep{30mm}\xymatrixcolsep{30mm}
\xymatrix{ A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\ C \ar[r] & D }
\]

\[
\xymatrix@R=30mm@C=30mm{ A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\ C \ar[r] & D }
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second example is identical to the first one, just for showing that the setting in the preamble is honored.

For overriding the values in a particular `\xymatrix` you can add `@C=<dimen>` and `@R=<dimen>`, instead of setting `\xymatrixrowsep` and `\xymatrixcolsep`. Handy if you have two diagrams in the same display.

Comment: Much appreciated!